# Rails AJAX shortcut?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

Using `remote:true` on a form, or something, and responding from the controller with `:js`, we can tell rails to execute some javascript file.

If you're destroying a user, for example. You'd have the User controller, and the Destroy action. You'd then have a file `views/users/destroy.js.erb` with something along the lines of:

```
$("ul#users").html("<%= j render partial: 'user_list' %>");
```

My question is... Is there a shortcut to just put that javascript in the controller, so that I don't have to have these tiny files littered about my app? If I'm only rendering a partial with some instance variables, and nothing else, I'd like to see something like:

```
respond_with render :js, with: 'partial_foo', on: '#selector .bar'
```

Is there such a shortcut?

Answer (score 0):

The only `shortcut` I could recommend for you is to use `json` and handle the response with your unobtrusive JS:

```
#view
<%= form_for @variable, remote: :true, method: :json %>

#controller
respond_to :json, :html

def action
    respond_with @variable
end
```

JSON sends small serialized data objects, meaning you won't have to handle any files, and can handle the data as required:

```
#app/assets/javascripts/application.js
$(element).on("ajax:success", function(data) {
    message = JSON.stringify(data);
    alert(message.attribute);
});
```

If you like this idea, I can come back with some ideas for handling the partial